# Is using @Ajax.ActionLink still the recommended way to get Ajax data with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting confused. I know there have been changes with regards to jQuery and I notice that in the MSDN documentation it states that to use Ajax.ActionLink I need the following libraries:

"Support for the client functionality of ASP.NET AJAX is in two script libraries: MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js. The release version and the debug version of these scripts are located in the project's Scripts folder. Before you can access these libraries in client script, you must add library references to the MVC views in the current project."

I thought these libraries were no longer recommended. In which case should I still do Ajax.Action link.

Here's what I was trying to implement:

[Ajax delete example](http://squarewidget.com/post/2011/06/Delete-Like-a-Rock-Star-with-MVC3,-Ajax-and-jQuery.aspx)

and the code example from above:

```
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Widget",
            new {id = item.Id},
            new AjaxOptions {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this widget?",
                OnSuccess = "deleteConfirmation"
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 the `Ajax.*` helpers use unobtrusive jQuery thanks to the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script. They no longer use any of the `Microsoft*.js` helpers if you enable unobtrusive javascript in your web.config (which is enabled by default when you create a new application):

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

What is obsolete is all the `Microsoft*.js` scripts that you have in the `Scripts` folder and which were used by `Ajax.*` helpers in previous ASP.NET MVC versions. They are provided only for backwards compatibility if you are upgrading from such previous version.

So in ASP.NET MVC 3, as long as you enabled unobtrusive javascript in your web.config and include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script you are safe to use `Ajax.*` helpers.